# replace password in a string with x's based on number of characters in password

Tags: c++, string

I have this string. and I need to find the last word in the string (which is the password) and replace it with x's for each character in the string. How can I do this with simple string functions? It needs to be able to work even if the password has characters and integers in it no matter with a varying length.

```
int main()
{
    string data = "Santa Claus 454-90-3424 sclaus password";

    cout << data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want my output to read: "Santa Claus 454-90-3424 sclaus xxxxxxxx"

Answer (score 3):

Use [`find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) to find bound of the last word, then [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) to fill it with x's.

Comment: is it too much to ask of you to type this out real quick? I'm really new to strings... (and programing in general) this is my first class

Comment: Why not use `std::rfind` if only one character is looked for, from the end?

Comment: @Benoit, Punctuation signs could be used as separators as I understand.

Comment: @Pete if you are new, that is all the more reason to **read the documentation, understand it, and figure out for yourself exactly what to write**. Programming is a task for people who like to think.

Comment: thanks guys. I guess I'll skip this for now and come back to it when i have enough time to think without stressing. I have 3 finals tomorrow besides programming ...

Comment: And isn't it better to use data.replace() here? Can someone comment on the merits/ demerits of using replace() vs. fill().

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in your previous question, tokenize it by spaces and replace the last one with Xs.

Comment: lol man. This isn't even graded. I just learn well by example. I see tokenizing is a valuable thing, but it seems to be beyond my abilities at the moment. This is my first programming class ever.

Comment: Look here: http://www.oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/CPPHOWTO/Volume/C++Programming-HOWTO-7.html

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t last_space = data.rfind(" ");
for(size_t = last_space + 1; pos < data.length(); ++pos) data[pos] = 'x';
```